# EventEmitter with Coffee SubClass Issues

Tags: javascript, node.js, coffeescript

I'm not sure why this doesn't work. Can someone clue me in? I don't see any events get logged, but they do get `emitted`...well, I think :)

```
{EventEmitter} = require 'events'

class Base extends EventEmitter

class App extends Base

  constructor: (cb) ->

    console.log 'setup'

    @on 'listener:1', (data) ->
      console.log 'listener 1: ' + data

    @on 'listener:2', (data) ->
      console.log 'listener 2: ' + data

    cb()

class One extends Base

  fire: () ->

    console.log 'fire 1'

    @emit 'listener:1', 1

class Two extends Base

  fire: () ->

    console.log 'fire 2'

    @emit 'listener:2', 2

new App(
  () ->
    setTimeout (->
      one = new One()
      one.fire()
      setTimeout (->
        two = new Two()
        two.fire()
      ), 2000
    ), 2000
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output of the program is as expected; Only `App` sets up listeners on itself, but it never `emit`s anything (only `One` and `Two`, which are *not* sublcasses of `App`, do so). Perhaps you're looking for something more like the following?

```coffeescript
{EventEmitter} = require 'events'

class Base extends EventEmitter
  constructor: ->
    console.log 'setup'

    @on 'listener:1', (data) ->
      console.log 'listener 1: ' + data

    @on 'listener:2', (data) ->
      console.log 'listener 2: ' + data

class App extends Base
  constructor: (cb) ->
    super()
    cb()

class One extends Base
  fire: ->
    console.log 'fire 1'
    @emit 'listener:1', 1

class Two extends Base
  fire: ->
    console.log 'fire 2'
    @emit 'listener:2', 2

new App(
  ->
    setTimeout (->
      one = new One()
      one.fire()
      setTimeout (->
        two = new Two()
        two.fire()
      ), 2000
    ), 2000
)
```

Comment: Well, when you put it that way! I guess I assumed EventEmitter was global, like process or something. Maybe I need to rethink this. Thanks!

Comment: Ah, gotcha. Nope, listeners to events are local to the EventEmitter instance `on` is called on. You *could* build a "global" EventEmitter by creating an instance of one and exporting it as a module--kind like an Event Bus or something.

Comment: That's exactly what I did :) Thanks!